# Stop VS validating js files on build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build-error

When I build a project I always get warnings and errors from my js files (downloaded from nuget) shown in the error list console.

For example:

> Error   eqeqeq  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.    Website C:\Code\Website\Scripts\modernizr-2.6.2.js  167

Is there any way to stop Visual Studio from showing (or even validating) these?

Answer (score 1):

[image: This will eliminate error messages (works with me) but if that's not what you want just strike off css and js validations under Text Editor]

Hope this helps.

This will eliminate error messages (works with me) but if that's not what you want just strike off css and js validations under Text Editor.

Comment: It doesn't work with me, I still get the same error after setting both options to false.

Comment: @MarcoLackovic Are there two ".eslintrc" and ".csslintrc" files under your C:\Users\%USERNAME%\ path?

Comment: I just updated to VS2015 update 3 and faced the same.
this solution works fine to me.